# Powershell & XML - nested nodes & xsi:type= blah blah blah

Tags: xml, nodes, powershell-3.0, game-development, xsitype

I run a dedicated server for an alpha/early access game called Space Engineers, occasionally they patch and break things and i am trying to create a powershell script to trouble shoot problems that may occur.  I am ok with powershell, never messed with XML.

The first step is disabling all objects in the game so that they cause less calculations on the server. like so ->

```
$power = Get-Content 'F:\DedicatedServer\DataDir\SE Survival 2\Saves\VPS RC 1\SANDBOX_0_0_0_.sbs' -raw
$power = $power -replace "<Enabled>true</Enabled>", "<Enabled>false</Enabled>"
$power | Out-File 'F:\DedicatedServer\DataDir\SE Survival 2\Saves\VPS RC 1\SANDBOX_0_0_0_.sbs' -Encoding ascii
```

The second and third steps will be to bring all medical rooms and power sources (not shown) online. This is where i get into trouble.

```
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content 'F:\DedicatedServer\DataDir\SE Survival 2\Saves\VPS RC 1\SANDBOX_0_0_0_.sbs'

$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($myXML.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

$node = $myXML.SelectNodes('//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock‌​[@xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom"]/Enabled', $ns) | % {    
    #set all med bays to be enabled.

    $switch= Select-XML -XML $myXML -XPath $node
    $switch.Node.InnerText = $switch.Node.InnerText.Replace("false", "true")

    $myXML.Save('F:\DedicatedServer\DataDir\SE Survival 2\Saves\VPS RC 1\SANDBOX_0_0_0_.sbs')
}
```

Here is an excerpt of the XML file with non relevant data removed -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyObjectBuilder_Sector xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Position>
  </Position>
  <SectorEvents> 
  </SectorEvents>
  <AppVersion>1044014</AppVersion>
  <SectorObjects>
    <MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_CubeGrid">
      <EntityId>72230476941025901</EntityId>
      <PersistentFlags>CastShadows InScene</PersistentFlags>
      <PositionAndOrientation>
      </PositionAndOrientation>
      <GridSizeEnum>Large</GridSizeEnum>
      <CubeBlocks>
        <MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock">          
        </MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock>
        <MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom">
          <SubtypeName>LargeMedicalRoom</SubtypeName>
          <EntityId>72107097601717796</EntityId>
          <Min x="4" y="1" z="-1" />
          <BlockOrientation Forward="Forward" Up="Up" />
          <ColorMaskHSV x="0" y="0.15" z="0.25" />
          <Owner>144233151425053409</Owner>
          <ShareMode>Faction</ShareMode>
          <CustomName>Lurch Enterprises</CustomName>
          <ShowOnHUD>false</ShowOnHUD>
          <Enabled>false</Enabled>
          <SteamUserId>0</SteamUserId>
        </MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock>
```

the XML file is not updating with the desired changes. Which are change every instance of

```
<MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom">
      <Enabled>false</Enabled>
```

to true.

The current errors are:

```
Select-Xml : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'XPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:16 char:44
+     $switch= Select-XML -XML $myXML -XPath $node
+                                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-Xml], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:17 char:5
+     $switch.Node.InnerText = $switch.Node.InnerText.Replace("false", "true")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

and answered! here is the final product that does what i wanted.

```
$filePath = '<your save file path here>\SANDBOX_0_0_0_.sbs'

#troubleshooting script
#switch EVERYTHING off
$power = Get-Content $filePath -raw
$power = $power -replace "<Enabled>true</Enabled>", "<Enabled>false</Enabled>"
$power | Out-File $filePath -Encoding ascii

#turn on medbays, reactors, batteries, solar panels ONLY
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content $filePath
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($myXML.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
$nodes = $myXML.SelectNodes("//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock[@xsi:type='MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom']/Enabled|//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock[@xsi:type='MyObjectBuilder_Reactor']/Enabled|//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock[@xsi:type='MyObjectBuilder_BatteryBlock']/Enabled|//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock[@xsi:type='MyObjectBuilder_SolarPanel']/Enabled", $ns)
ForEach($node in $nodes)
{
$node.InnerText = "true"
}
$myXML.Save($filePath)
```

Comment: I have updated the original question with the current lines in powershell. still trying to figure out why my file is not getting updated with the changes. i suspect it is because my selectnodes path is incorrect and / or a combination of not placing the $myXML.save line in the right area.

Comment: Is there really anything in this question related to [tag:video-game-consoles]? This just seems to be a PowerShell/XML question.

Comment: well I am a new user and do not have enough rep to create a new tag.

Space Engineers is a PC game.

Comment: i changed the tag to Gaming to hopefully be more generic but still applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `xsi` prefix in your XPath you need to register prefix-to-namespace URI mapping to `XmlNamespaceManager`, then pass the `XmlNamespaceManager` to `SelectNodes()` method  :

```
.....
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($myXML.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
$node = $myXML.SelectNodes("your xpath that contains xsi prefix here", $ns)
.....
```

**UPDATE :**

Turned out there was hidden character before `[` in your XPath that's why you got "invalid token" error. I'm not familiar with PowerShell specific syntax, but this worked fine for me :

```
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content "F:\DedicatedServer\DataDir\SE Survival 2\Saves\VPS RC 1\SANDBOX_0_0_0_.sbs"

$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($myXML.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
$nodes = $myXML.SelectNodes("//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock[@xsi:type='MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom']/Enabled", $ns)
ForEach($node in $nodes)
{
    $node.InnerText = "true"
}
$myXML.Save("F:\DedicatedServer\DataDir\SE Survival 2\Saves\VPS RC 1\SANDBOX_0_0_0_.sbs")
```

Comment: ah yes, i was reading about this all night. i will give it another go with your info.

Comment: your answer got me farther along. I no longer get that error, however i was expecting another error about my path when using selectnodes.  I was surprised to find that the script reported having completed with no errors, however the file specified for the xml save did not update. thank you for your help so far. I will continue to experiment.

Comment: @JasonT.LeBoeuf try this XPath : `//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock[@xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom"]/Enabled`

Comment: funny enough that got me an error.

Exception calling "SelectNodes" with "2" argument(s): "'//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock‌​[@xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom"]/Enabled' has an 
invalid token."
At line:11 char:1
+ $node = $myXML.SelectNodes('//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlock ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: hmm.. strange if that's because `//` operator not supported. If this is really the case, try to replace `//` with `/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock/`

Comment: or try to use double-quotes to wrap the entire XPath, and use single-quotes for 'MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom' part in the Xpath, if you haven't tried this way

Comment: ok, so the token error, I think that had to do with the XSI prefix. so for now I will put that aside and will use the path //SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock/Enabled.  This is working and now producing errors regarding the next few lines. I will add those errors in the next couple of comments.

Comment: Select-Xml : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'XPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:18 char:43
+     $switch=Select-XML -XML $myXML -XPath $node
+                                           ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-Xml], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:19 char:5
+     $switch.Node.InnerText = $switch.Node.InnerText.Replace("false", "true")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: post your latest code so I can check (Edit your question and put the latest code there, not in comment)

Comment: i have updated to the latest code and error messages. thank you for continuing to help!

Comment: removed all lines that were supposed to be commented out to avoid confusion.

Comment: hey man, i updated the question with the finished code. does everything i wanted. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do more XML modification you might find it more useful to use native XML technologies. So although it doesn't solve the problem like you tried to I'd like to offer you a solution using [BaseX](http://basex.org) (full disclosure: I am a member of the project team). Personally, I find it much simpler instead of using scripting solutions. After downloading you can run BaseX using:

```
basex -u -i input.xml query.xq
```

This assumes your input is in the `input.xml` file. The `-u` flag states that updates to the file should be propagated back to the file. The query is stored in query.xq aand has the following content:

```
//SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock[@xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom"]/Enabled[. = "false"] ! (replace value of node . with 'true')
```

This simple states to replace each Enabled element with text equal to false to be replaced with true. It uses a simple XQuery Update expression. The `!` notation is just a handy shortening, the following query does the same, but might be slightly more readable:

```
for $e in //SectorObjects/MyObjectBuilder_EntityBase/CubeBlocks/MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock[@xsi:type="MyObjectBuilder_MedicalRoom"]/Enabled[. = "false"]
return replace value of node . with 'true'
```

To me, these two lines (one for executing the program, one for the XQuery) do look like much simpler.